# Are Jacobian matrices associated with Cartesian to spherical coordinates transformation inverses of each other?

Tags: coordinate-systems, transformation, spherical-coordinates, jacobian

Consider the relationships between Cartesian and spherical coordinates as explained [in this webpage](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).

Cartesian coordinates are given in terms of spherical coordinates according to the following relationships:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
x(r,\theta,\phi)&=&r\cos\theta\sin\phi\\
y(r,\theta,\phi)&=&r\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z(r,\theta,\phi)&=&r\cos\phi
\end{array}
$$

Spherical coordinates are given in terms of Cartesian coordinates according to the following relationships:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
r(x,y,z)&=&\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
\theta(x,y,z)&=&\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\\
\phi(x,y,z)&=&\arccos\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)
\end{array}
$$

Let us call $J$ the Jacobian matrix associated with the transformation from Cartesian to spherical coordinates as:
$$
J = \frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta\sin\phi & -r\sin\theta\sin\phi & r\cos\theta\cos\phi \\
\sin\theta\sin\phi & r\cos\theta\sin\phi & r\sin\theta\cos\phi \\
cos\phi & 0 & -r\sin\phi
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let us call $J'$ the Jacobian matrix associated with the transformation from spherical to Cartesian coordinates as
$$
J' = \frac{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}{\partial(x,y,z)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac xr & \frac yr & \frac zr\\
\frac{-y}{r^2-z^2} & \frac{x}{r^2-z^2} & 0 \\
\frac{xz}{r^2\sqrt{r^2-z^2}} & \frac{yz}{r^2\sqrt{r^2-z^2}} & \frac{-x^2-y^2}{r\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

After transforming $J'$ into spherical coordinates by replacing the set $(x,y,z)$ variables, it becomes

$$
J' = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta\sin\phi & \sin\theta\sin\phi & \cos\phi\\
\frac{-\sin\theta}{r\sin\phi} & \frac{\cos\theta}{r\sin\phi} & 0 \\
\frac{\cos\theta\cos\phi}{r} & \frac{\sin\theta\cos\phi}{r} & \frac{-\sin\phi}{r}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In a book on tensor calculus (Introduction to tensor analysis and the calculus of moving surfaces, P. Grinfeld), it is stated that the product $JJ'$ should amount to the identity matrix for arbitrary transformations in the Euclidean space. However, the product

$$
JJ'=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi & -r\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi & r^2\cos\theta\cos^2\phi\\
\frac{-sin^2\theta}{r} & \cos^2\theta & 0\\
\frac{\cos\theta\cos^2\phi}{r} & 0 & \sin^2\phi
\end{bmatrix} \neq \mathbf{I}
$$

As we can see the above product is not the identity matrix. Therefore, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You appear to just be rewriting $J$ in spherical coordinates. If you work out the second Jacobian from first principles, it should be $J^{-1}$.

Comment: @J.G. I have trouble seeing what you imply. Notice that the position of the sole zero element in J and J' is different. Therefore I am not just rewriting J in spherical coordinates... However, what do you mean by first principles? Maybe that is what I am missing.

Comment: You have an error in $\partial x / \partial r$; could that be the problem?

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial (r\cos\theta\sin\phi)}{\partial r} = \cos\theta\sin\phi$ as in the first element of $J$ matrix. Where is the error?

Comment: Oops, I meant $\partial x / \partial\phi$.

Comment: Your matrix multiplication above is not matrix multiplication.  You have just multiplied the corresponding entries.  Each entry should be the dot product of appropriate rows vs. columns.